# Link meta.stackoverflow with meta.stackexchange similar questions

Tags: feature-request, mso-mse-split

I recently asked a question on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269147/new-badge-good-comment), which almost immediately returned a response of already answered on Meta Stack Exchange, which is fine. However, when asking the question the similar question didn't come up in 'similar questions' and even when I use the exact title, it doesn't work.

Not sure whether this is even remotely possible, and would probably only apply to these two sites.

Perhaps I should have searched meta first, but I use the ask a question as a search tool (I can't be the only one) to make sure that the question has not been asked before.

Comment: Thanks, interestingly this didn't come up in similar questions! How meta.